# Using dynamic variables with isset()?

Tags: php, variables, isset

I have a loop that has a dynamic variable in it, eg:

```
while(i < 10){
  echo  ${"dynamic" . $i . "var"};
  $i++;
};
```

I want to only echo the variable if the original var (say `$dynamic3var`) is set so I add:

```
while(i < 10){
  if(isset(${"dynamic" . $i . "var"})){
    echo  ${"dynamic" . $i . "var"};
  $i++;
  };
};
```

However this wont work as its still picking up `$i`.

Does anyone know a correct way of doing this?

Comment: what o/p you are getting on running the codes provided in answers ?

Comment: Plz post where you have declared the variable say `$dynamic3var` in the code

Answer (score 1):

Since global variables are bad ideas you should rethink your code. A plain refactoring would be to use an associative array (even if it remains a global variable at the first step). Then you could work with

```
if( isset($dynamic[$i]) ) ...
```

Why are Globals evil? Read this: http://tomnomnom.com/posts/why-global-state-is-the-devil-and-how-to-avoid-using-it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while($i < 10){
  $label = "dynamic".$i."var";

  if(isset($$label))
    echo $$label;

  $i ++;
};
```

Comment: Thanks but no luck there

Comment: Well then there is a bug elsewhere in your code or you aren't using an up to date PHP version. If I run the code on http://writecodeonline.com/php/ it works perfectly.

Comment: Give your explanation too.